# Django object matching query does not exist

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a problem with this code, it just doesn't want to pass to `except`:

```
try:
    tariff = Cost.objects.get(language__name=order.language_destination.name, type__name=order.type.name)
except Cost.DoesNotExist:
    tariff = Cost.objects.get(language__name=order.language_source.name, type__name=order.type.name)
else:
    pass
```

Every time it stops at `try` and it gives me:

```
DoesNotExist at /shop/orders/doc/

Cost matching query does not exist.
```

Any ideea why it's not getting the except code?

Full traceback after adding the `else`:

```
nternal Server Error: /shop/orders/doc/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crm/application/agency/views.py", line 156, in order_document
    tariff = Cost.objects.get(language__name=order.language_destination.name, type__name=order.type.name)
  File "crm/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "crm/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 380, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
order.models.DoesNotExist: Cost matching query does not exist.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crm/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "crm/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "crm/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "crm/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "crm/application/agency/views.py", line 165, in order_document
    tariff = Cost.objects.get(language__name=order.language_source.name, type__name=order.type.name)
  File "crm/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "crm/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 380, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
order.models.DoesNotExist: Cost matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the line that the error occurs? Show the full traceback. Have you tried to raise an explicit exception? Works?

Comment: @nik_m, I guess it fails on second query, not on first one that is enclosed into a try-catch.

Comment: yes it seems it's on second query aswell, let me and an else to see if it changes

Comment: @NitaAlexandru, I just posted an approach solution. Be free to test it.

Comment: i saw it, i edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If fails because don't exists any "object" for "destination" neither for "source".

You can rewrite your code like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

q1 = Q(language__name=order.language_destination.name)
q2 = Q(language__name=order.language_source.name)
q3 = Q(type__name=order.type.name)

if Cost.objects.filter( q1&q3 ).exists():
    tariff = Cost.objects.get( q1&q3 )
elif Cost.objects.filter( q2&q3 ).exists():
    tariff = Cost.objects.get( q2&q3 )
else:
    *** NOT FOUND ***
```

But this is just aesthetic changes to avoid exceptions. May be a more elegant and fast approach is using [first()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#first):

```
tariff = ( Cost.objects.filter( q1&q3 ).first() or
           Cost.objects.filter( q2&q3 ).first()
         )

if not tariff:
    *** NOT FOUND ***
```